# Why would one choose standalone socket.io server vs. Express vs. node http?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm making my first steps in websockets and socket.io and going through some tutorials online.

[This tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/beyond-rest-using-websockets-for-two-way-communication-in-your-react-app-884eff6655f5) is using what seems to be socket.io's standalone server. My question is what is the motivation for using a standalone server over using Express (or node http server for that matter).

I tried searching online but couldn't find what would be the motivation to use a standalone server.

Answer (score 0):

I stepped over the same question and what I could see is that adding Express is only a convenience to have more functionality in the same application using the same server and port altogether.

If we don't need extra functionality, server.io standalone is just fine. In fact, it is the better option because we get a leaner and simpler code.

Adding Express, the same server in the same port is capable of serving html pages, routing and everything that Express API can offer. We can do this:

```
const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer);

// Express working..
app.get("/:file", (req, res) => {
  const file = req.params.file;
  console.log("io: Got hit at", file, "ts:", Date.now());
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/html/" + file);
});

// socket.io working
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("message", (data) => {
    // do something
  }
}

httpServer.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("socket.io and Express listening together on *:3000");
});
```

As far as I could dig in the docs of both packages, Express will not add any extra benefit to socket.io dealing with socket requests and responses, security increase or anything else.

Summarizing, only use Express to have the same server and port dealing with socket.io convenience together with Express http page serving, routing and etc.

Answer (score -1):

This is all you need to have knowledge about differences between two of them: https://github.com/rsp/node-websocket-vs-socket.io

There are few common misconceptions regarding WebSocket and Socket.IO:

- The first misconception is that using Socket.IO is significantly easier than using WebSocket which doesn't seem to be the case. See examples below.
- The second misconception is that WebSocket is not widely supported in the browsers. See below for more info.
- The third misconception is that Socket.IO downgrades the connection as a fallback on older browsers. It actually assumes that the browser is old and starts an AJAX connection to the server, that gets later upgraded on browsers supporting WebSocket, after some traffic is exchanged.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. The question is not about WebSockets vs Socket.IO, but rather using the standalone initialization method (https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-initialization/#Standalone) `const io = require('socket.io')()` rather than integrating it with a `http.Server` instance.